# Using google docs API in asp.net website

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

Is it possible to edit and format Google documents(word, text-file, excel, PPT, PDF) using Google Docs API.

All i could do so far create, download, upload, delete file and replace with with another one.
i want for example if user hit **bold** button then i could use a class in Google Docs API to format the text to be **bold**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, you cannot edit the content using the [Google Documents List API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list). You can edit spreadsheets using the [Google Spreadsheet API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/), and for scripts to run inside Google Docs, you can use [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/).